# Why is Gradle not applying the dependency scope correctly under sourceSets in IntelliJ 2016?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, dependency-management

I have a gradle project with a single module.

I have declared the 'provided' configuration to enable provided-scoped dependencies in the parent `build.gradle` file:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'

    configurations {
        provided
    }

    idea {
        module {
            scopes.PROVIDED.plus += [configurations.provided]
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
        test.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
        test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.provided
    }

    ... other stuff...
}
```

In the module `build.gradle` I have declared the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:2.3.1:tests'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:2.3.1'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'
    provided 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.12'
}
```

When I expand the Gradle tool window, it declares the second to last dependency there as provided as well, even though it has compile scope:

[image: Screen shot of Gradle tool window]

I would expect to see the dependency listed with `(Compile)` next to it in this tool window, not `(Provided)`.

So the question is: Why aren't I?

Is it because the implementation of slf4j (slf4j-simple) is provided, and depends on slf4j-api, so automatically makes that one provided as well? How do I stop that? Should I be stopping that? I want the API as a compiled dependency, but I want projects that use this to decide on their own implementation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the very same problem with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate build 163.12024.16. I wasn't able to fix it. BUT it magically disappeared when I upgraded to build 171.4249.39. (When using the previous build again, the scope goes back to the incorrect "provided" again.)